# Draw lines at an angle in jetpack compose without a canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

so I wanted to draw a line at an angle from point A to point B in jetpack compose.
Is there a way to do it without a canvas, since a canvas won't really work with what I want to do

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw behind other composables you can use the `drawBehind` modifier.

If you want to draw both behind and in front you can use the `drawWithContent`modifier.

If you also want to cache the result as much as possible you can use the `drawWithCache` modifier.

Example of a line behind the content and a line in front of the content using the `drawWithCache` modifier

```
@Composable
fun DrawWithCacheExample() {
    val width = 400.dp
    val height = 200.dp
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(width, height)
            .border(1f.dp, Color.Black, RectangleShape)
            .drawWithCache {
                onDrawWithContent {
                    // draw behind the content
                    drawLine(Color.Black, Offset.Zero, Offset(width.toPx(), height.toPx()), 1f)
                    // draw the content
                    drawContent()
                    // draw in front of the content
                    drawLine(Color.Black, Offset(0f, height.toPx()), Offset(width.toPx(), 0f), 1f)
                }
            }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(width / 2, height / 2)
            .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), (height / 4).roundToPx()) }
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .draggable(
                orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                    offsetX += delta
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```